# Update Model From Database EF Core/.NET Core

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have reverse engineered our model from an existing database using EF Core Scaffold-DbContext. Since then a couple of tables have been added to the database within SSMS and I now need to update the model.  How can I do this without overwriting the original model classes (changes have been made to them)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not make changes to the generated code, they are generated as partial classes, so you can make another file with your changes, and then simply re-generate the files.